# How to fix unknown elements of vue-router (e.g. router-view, router-link)?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I set up a new vue-project that was created using vue ui and manually selecting the features.

- The features are the following:

  - Babel
  - Router
  - Vuex
  - Use config files

and only that, and run the project using the development mode; however, an error occur in the console (Dev tools) showing an unknown elements for router-link and router-view.

https://github.com/JeromeDeLeon/vue-router-bug

That is the repo (a newly created one like hello world program). I already posted an issue on vue-router github page but eventually got closed because they said that everything was working properly, but it is not working for me.

- I tried changing the Router to VueRouter on router.js, but the result is still the same.
- I tried transferring the code of router.js to main.js, but still not working.

The expected result is to show the content of Home.vue in order to check if router is working.

The actual result shows the "Home | About" only in the top-middle of the browser and nothing else.

Comment: I pulled your repository and it worked fine. Your problem is most likely having global npm packages installed at conflicting versions.

Comment: What are your **node** and **npm** versions? Also, try to clear npm cache `npm cache clean`, remove `node_modules` and try `npm install` after.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, I have the following npm packages installed globally,
- angular/cli 6.2.8
- vue/cli 3.2.1
- vue/cli-service-global 3.2.1
- browserify 16.2.3
- node-gyp 3.8.0
- nodemon 1.18.9
- npm 6.5.0
- uglify-js 3.4.9

Comment: @ljubadr, I am using node 10.14.2 and npm 6.5.0

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I tried to reinstall node or use different version like node 8.15 but still problem persist. Tell me the config when you run my repo. even the version of your browser. Thanks